# How do I find all solutions to a "Generate and Test" task in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to solve the following problem with Prolog to improve / test my Prolog knowledge.

> Find three digits X, Y and Z such that XYZ in base10 is equal to ZYX in base9

Source: [Coffee Time Challenges](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/june22014/index.html)

As I have already solved it with some other languages, I know that the solutions are:

- (X, Y, Z) = (0, 0, 0)
- (X, Y, Z) = (4, 4, 5)

I solved it in the other languages by generating all cominations for X, Y, Z (10^3 = 1000 combinations) and testing if the condition is true.

### Test with Prolog

With Prolog, I wrote the following testing procedure:

```
is_solution(X, Y, Z) :- 9>=X, X>=0, 9>=Y, Y>=0, 9>=Z, Z>=0,
                        base10 is (100*X + 10*Y + Z), base9 is (9*9*Z+9*Y+X),
                        base10 = base9.
```

But there seems to be something wrong:

```
?- is_solution(0,0,0).
false.

?- is_solution(4,4,5).
false.
```

### Generating all solutions

I thought I could simply get the solutions by `swipl -f main.prolog`:

```
is_solution(X,Y,Z).
ERROR: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can I fix that

### Printing everything without user-interaction

Finally, I would like to have an executable script that prints all solutions without user interaction. I have seen `findall` and I guess that I would have to use it here, but I have never (successfully) used it so far. Can you please show me how to print all solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prolog variables start with an uppercase letter or an underscore, so neither `base9` nor `base10` are variables. If you change this to `Base9` and `Base10`, your solution will work for concrete instantiations.

To make it work for variables, and to avoid generating all combinations, consider using *constraints*, which typically significantly reduce the search space and are a more general alternative to lower-level arithmetic. For example, in SICStus and SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

is_solution(X, Y, Z) :- 
    [X,Y,Z] ins 0..9,
    9*9*Z+9*Y+X #= 100*X + 10*Y + Z.
```

Example query:

```
?- is_solution(X, Y, Z), label([X,Y,Z]).
X = Y, Y = Z, Z = 0 ;
X = Y, Y = 4, Z = 5.
```

Or with `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(triple(X,Y,Z), (is_solution(X, Y, Z), label([X,Y,Z])), Triples).
Triples = [triple(0, 0, 0), triple(4, 4, 5)].
```

To print all solutions, print them yourself:

```
?- is_solution(X, Y, Z), label([X,Y,Z]), format("solution: ~w ~w ~w\n", [X,Y,Z]), false.
solution: 0 0 0
solution: 4 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the complete source code here: https://github.com/schickling/challenges/blob/master/coffee-time-challenges/01-two-bases/main.prolog

Comment: In that snippet, `range/3`is completely superfluous, and the three `between/3` calls can be more compactly written as `maplist(between(0,9), [X,Y,Z])`. As I said though, consider using constraints as a more general alternative to such low-level enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, I removed `range/3`. Yes, `maplist(between(0,9), [X,Y,Z])` is more compact. But I still prefer the three `between(0,9,X)` calls, because I really understand them and I know how to adjust them for other problems.

Comment: Also consider adjusting your incoherent indentation: `main/0` is indented in conventional Prolog style, whereas `is_solution/3` is not.

Comment: I've updated the indentation. Is it now the usual Prolog style?

Comment: If you insist on not using constraints, at least consider using `(=:=)/2` to compare arithmetic expressions. For example, instead of `Base10 is (100*X + 10*Y + Z), Base9 is (9*9*Z+9*Y+X), Base10 = Base9`, you can write: `100*X + 10*Y + Z =:= 9*9*Z + 9*Y + X`. The multiple `between/3` calls are not very elegant: Either use `maplist/2`, as I already recommended, or an auxiliary predicate like `digit(D) :- between(0, 9, D).`. You can then use `maplist(digit, [X,Y,Z])` if you do not understand the other form.